# How to convert a PDF from HTML using C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Can anyone tell me how to convert a PDF document from an HTML code using C#? I'm using itextsharp 5.0.2 dll. I have come across this forum. I didnt find any solution so far. And some of them mentioned iTextSharp.HtmlParser but i cannot find such kind of class in my version of dll. In which version should i need to use to achieve my task.

I have tried with this code...i dont know what wrong did i do? Im not getting the PDF file.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestResult.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

StringBuilder htmlText =
            new StringBuilder("<table style='color:red;' border='1'>");
htmlText.Append("<tr><th>Karunagara Pandi</th><tr><td> Software Engineer</td></tr></table>");

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(htmlText.ToString());
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
List<iTextSharp.text.IElement> elements = 
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(stringReader, null);
doc.Open();
foreach (object item in elements)
{
    doc.Add((IElement)item);
}

// Response Output
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);
doc.Open();

//doc.Close();

Response.Write("PDF is created");
```

This code also taken from this site only....I need to your proper solution. I'll also try to get.....

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have two `doc.Open` statements without an intervening `doc.Close()`. The second one will effectively overwrite the contents you've just added.

```
doc.Open();  // ONE
foreach (object item in elements)
{
    doc.Add((IElement)item);
}

// Response Output
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);
doc.Open();  // TWO
```